# PHP multiple uploads with PHP functions

Tags: php, pdo, foreach

I try to understand how to use multiple uploads in PDO.

So I have my post.php:

```
$database = new Database();
$db = $database->getConnection(); 
$media = new Media($db);

if($_POST){

 $image = !empty($_FILES["image"]["name"]) ? sha1_file($_FILES['image']['tmp_name']) . "-" .  time() .  "-" . basename($_FILES["image"]["name"]) : ""; 
 $media->image = $image;    

   if ($media->create()) {
     echo $media->uploadPhoto();
     $_POST=array();
   }
}

 <input name="image[]" type="file" />
```

And my media.php with pdo query and some upload validations:

```
  public $image; 
  public $created;  

    public function create(){

    //write query
    $query = "INSERT INTO " . $this->table_name . "
    SET image=:image, 
    created=:created";

    $stmt = $this->conn->prepare($query);

    $this->image=htmlspecialchars(strip_tags($this->image));
    $stmt->bindParam(":image", $this->image);

    if($stmt->execute()){
        return true;
    }

    print_r($stmt->errorInfo());
    return false;
 }
 function uploadPhoto(){

    $result_message="";

    if(!empty($_FILES["image"]["tmp_name"])){
        $target_directory = "../uploads/";
        $target_file = $target_directory . $this->image;
        $file_type = pathinfo($target_file, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
        $file_upload_error_messages="";
        $check = getimagesize($_FILES["image"]["tmp_name"]);
        if($check!==false){
        }else{
        $file_upload_error_messages.="<div></div>";
        }
        $allowed_file_types=array("jpg", "JPG", "jpeg", "JPEG", "png", "PNG", "gif", "GIF");
        if(!in_array($file_type, $allowed_file_types)){
           $file_upload_error_messages.="<div></div>";
        }
        if(file_exists($target_file)){
        }
        if($_FILES['image']['size'] > (10485760)){
        $file_upload_error_messages.="<div></div>";
        }
        if(!is_dir($target_directory)){
           mkdir($target_directory, 0777, true);
        }
        if(empty($file_upload_error_messages)){
            if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES["image"]["tmp_name"], $target_file)){
            }else{
                $result_message.="<div></div>";
            }
        }
        else{
           $result_message.="{$file_upload_error_messages}";
        }
    }
    return $result_message;
}
```

So I need to store the values in different mysql records and upload them all to the server.

What is the best way to do this and where to place the foreach? 
I struggle with the right place of the foreach ...

```
$x=0;  
foreach ( $_FILES['image']['name'] AS $key => $value ){  
    // ...
    $x++;  
}
```

Comment: Please format your question properly and add _all_ relevant code. You should also tell us what the actual issue is. Where exactly are you stuck? Example: You're calling `$media->create()` that does some DB stuff, but we can't see what since you didn't post the full method. You're not passing anything to that function either.

Comment: you are missing a `"` in your `create` function (maybe just here in SO, but you should format the code better)

Comment: I added the relevant code. It issn´t clear for me how to foreach the function uploadPhoto() to insert multiple (and not only one) image.

Comment: Your first mistake is making a database wrapper, when you already have PDO. And just because you use it, that does not mean your code is magically object-oriented.

Answer (score 0):

so if this is your foreach loop and you want to insert different records for each uploaded file then use mysqli_multi_query

```
  $x=0;  
  $query = "";
  foreach ( $_FILES['image']['name'] AS $key => $value ){  
     $query .= 'insert into tableName (col1,col2,col3,image)VALUES("a","b","c","'.$value.'");';
     $x++;  
  }
  $query = rtrim($query,";");
  mysqli_multi_query($connectionObj,$query);
```

Your query will look somthing like this

```
insert into tableName (col1,col2,col3,image)VALUES("a","b","c","a.jpg");
insert into tableName (col1,col2,col3,image)VALUES("a","b","c","b.jpg");
```

Comment: This isn't using PDO (read: http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php)

Comment: well you can use my logic execute query in loop when all execution is done then close the connection not before because it will slow down the process

Comment: Ok i see, i´ve to rewrite my code ... i wanted to have it in oop/function but seems like i have to write everything in the same file.